# Only custom Domain should be able to see on google for community- Website

Tags: custom-domain

I've created a community, and setup a custom domain name for community.

Consider:
My community URL : www.xyz.force.com.

Customized domain name for community : www.xyz.com.

When I'm searching for website in google, it shows the pages with link like; www.xyz.force.com/... This should not be happen. means customer should not be able to see  standard domain name of community.

Customer should be able to see the link on google like; www.xyz.com/...

Please check below screenshot: 
[image]

I've already submitted the sitemap.xml file to google webmaster tool more than 2 -3 week ago.

Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: I faced similar issues in past. It seems in some of your community pages or external websites has links to https://shipperman-portal.force.com/contactus instead of https://www.shipperman.us/contactus. Try to find out those pages and change the link accordingly. When the search engines will do the next crawl this search result will be removed. Please try this and post your findings.

Comment: @SarojBera I've checked the pages but no such link available in page. I've refered the page link like " <a href="aboutus" ">About Us</a>"

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario robot.txt file need to be taken into consideration.The robot.txt file is responsible for SEO crawl , Check this URL for the same : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: I've submited the robot.txt file to Google webmaster and its current status is active. More than 1 month time is spend.  Still its showing me as my question. you can check sitemap here "https://www.shipperman.us/sitemap"